# Ruby: How to count the number of times a string appears in another string?

Tags: ruby, string, count

I'm trying to count the number of times a string appears in another string.

I know you can count the number of times a letter appears in a string:

```
string = "aabbccddbb"
string.count('a')
=> 2
```

But if I search for how many times 'aa' appears in this string, I also get two.

```
string.count('aa')
=> 2
```

I don't understand this. I put the value in quotation marks, so I'm searching for the number of times the exact string appears, not just the letters.

Comment: Please clarify (with an edit): does `'aa'` appear once or twice in the string `'aaa'`.

Comment: It should probably be twice in that case. Positions 0 and 1 && Positions 1 and 2

Comment: Certainly, you are an excellent poster. I rewarded you Cary Swoveland.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here are two ways to count the numbers of times a given substring appears in a string (the first being my preference). Note (as confirmed by the OP) the substring `'aa'` appears twice in the string `'aaa'`, and therefore five times in:

```
str = "aaabbccaaaaddbab"
```

**1. Use [String#scan](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regex that contains a positive lookahead that looks for the given substring**

```
def count_em(str, substr)
  str.scan(/(?=#{substr})/).count
end
```

```
count_em(str,"aa")
  #=> 5
count_em(str,"ab")
  #=> 2
```

Note:

```
"aaabbccaaaaddbab".scan(/(?=aa)/)
  #=> ["", "", "", "", ""]
```

A positive lookbehind produces the same result:

```
"aaabbccaaaaddbab".scan(/(?<=aa)/)
  #=> ["", "", "", "", ""]
```

As well, `String#scan` could be replaced with the form of [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument (here the same regular expression) and no block, and returns an enumerator. That form of `gsub` in unusual in that has nothing to do with character replacement; it simply generates matches of the regular expression.

**2. Convert given string to an array of characters, apply [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) then [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), then [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count)**

```
def count_em(str, substr)
  subarr = substr.chars
  str.each_char
     .each_cons(substr.size)
     .count(subarr)
end
```

```
count_em(str,"aa")
  #=> 5
count_em(str,"ab")
  #=> 2
```

We have:

```
subarr = "aa".chars
  #=> ["a", "a"]
enum0 = "aaabbccaaaaddbab".each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "aaabbccaaaaddbab":each_char>
```

We can see the elements that will generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a",
  #    "a", "d", "d", "b", "a", "b"]

enum1 = enum0.each_cons("aa".size)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:
  #      "aaabbccaaaaddbab":each_char>:each_cons(2)>
```

Convert `enum1` to an array to see what values the enumerator will pass on to `map`:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "b"], ["b", "b"], ["b", "c"],
  #    ["c", "c"], ["c", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], 
  #    ["a", "d"], ["d", "d"], ["d", "b"], ["b", "a"],
  #    ["a", "b"]]
 
enum1.count(subarr)
  #=> enum1.count(["a", "a"])
  #=> 5
```

Answer (score 63):

It's because the [`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-count) counts *characters*, not instances of strings. In this case `'aa'` means the same thing as `'a'`, it's considered a set of characters to count.

To count the number of times `aa` appears in the string:

```
string = "aabbccddbb"
string.scan(/aa/).length
# => 1
string.scan(/bb/).length
# => 2
string.scan(/ff/).length
# => 0
```

Comment: I see, to find the count of actual strings, you use the scan method instead of the count method. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah [`scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) takes a regular expression like `/aa/` or even a string like `"aa"` if you prefer and returns the matches. `length` tells you how many matches if you don't care what the matches are.

Comment: You can also use count or size instead of length

Comment: There is no reason to use a Regexp instead of a String in this example.

Comment: Good answer. Worked on ruby 2.1.5 !

Answer (score -5):

try to use
string.split('a').count - 1

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you possibly elaborate on your answer a bit? It would help others in the future who might have this same question if you could explain the logic behind your solution!

Comment: "a".split('a').count == 0; "ba".split('a').count == 1; "bad".split('a').count == 2;